# how to remove object property and take specific values from array by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

from this array:

```
var arr = [
    {
    element: 'anything',
    order: 1
  }, 
  {
    element: 'something',
    order: 2
  }
]
```

I want to generate this:

```
arr = ['anything', 'something'];
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the map function

```
var arr2 = arr.map(x => x.element);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Or even more concise: `arr.map(x => x.element)` ;)

Comment: And, perhaps worth noting, no jQuery needed-- this is vanilla JS.

Comment: Worth noting that arrow functions do not work in Internet Explorer 11 (for those stuck with legacy users).

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like

```
var newArr = [];
$.each(arr, function(index, value) {
    newArr.push(value);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use vanilla js: as shown by @James L.:

`arr.map(x => x.element);`

or use jQuery Map function:

```
$.map(arr, function(val, i){
  return val.element;
})
```

See Docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/